# How to pump tire with cap that won't come off

Tags: maintenance, tire

I have a Schwinn bike from probably mid 2000's. The front tire has a regular valve cap that I can twist off and pump with a floor pump. The back tire has an oval cap that I cannot get off. And it seems like it is attached onto a tube, not just a regular valve like the front tire. I can't pull off the cap or twist it off. Not sure how to get it off to pump the tire.

I don't bike a ton and am not sure if I am using the right terminology. It might be too vague but if anyone knows what I am talking about I appreciate the advice!

Comment: Picture? I've never heard of an oval cap.

Comment: This is a question that appears to have no duplicates.  Thank you!  Please use the edit link under your question, to post more information.  A couple of good photos showing the valve up close would be really helpful.

Comment: Sounds to me like the cap is either squashed and deformed, or its an aero one that is stuck on with some sort of adhesive.   Third option is that its a novelty shaped cap that has been glued on or has been overtightened and the threads have deformed and got purchase on the body of the valve stem.  Sounds like a case for pliers and brute-force.   I've never seen a cap with left-hand thread, so its very likely a normal righty-tighty thread.

Comment: @Criggie or in this case, ideally lefty-loosey

Comment: Vote to leave open for now, pending further information.  Its pretty clear what @Claire is asking, but a picture will help clarify.

Comment: I'm guessing that the "oval" one might be a Schrader valve with the valve core partly unscrewed.

Comment: If all else fails, drag it to the nearest bike shop and have them figure it out.

Comment: Photos of the valves would help a lot. :)

Comment: Vote to close - question is a week old and OP has not supplied further information.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your description you have two different tubes: one with [Presta valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presta_valve#/media/File:Presta_valve_close.jpg) and the other with [Schreder valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve#/media/File:Valvola_Schrader.jpg). Both should have protective plastic caps that should pretty easily come off. It might be possible that cap on the rear wheel valve is stuck so some pliers might help to unscrew it.

Regarding pumping tires, your floor pump should have [adapter](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81lW%2Bad3KrL._SY500_.jpg) for both valve types so you should use one that fits.

Maybe, if you have pump for only one valve type, you could consider changing your tubes to be of the same type (that matches the pump). Anyway, it is recommended to change tubes because they get porous and leak air (especially if they are too old).

Comment: I'm not seeing the oval even if one is presta or woods.

Comment: Tires (unless tubeless) don't hold the air in and can be porous with no effect. Tires hold the tube. The tube holds the air.

Comment: My English is confusing sometimes :) I guess I've made mistake tire/tube.

Comment: @Batman There are all kinds and shapes of [valve caps](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ba/en/valve-caps) - CRC has only a modest collection of what you can find on the internet :)